# Are rules of an organization on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are rules about a non-governmental organization on-topic on this site? For example, "Are there minimum vision requirements to compete in biathlon at the Olympic Games?". Other questions could involve the penalty for a Boy Scout being caught lying to their group leader, the requirements for becoming a Freemason, or whether the rules of a specific private university allow a student's grade to be lowered as punishment for a non-academic conduct violation and, if so, what the burden of proof is.

Answer (score 12):

I would argue no.

We are experts in law, not experts in internal rules (published or not) of private organizations.

We could answer questions about whether a particular organization's rule is contrary to statute, or whether statute requires certain types of organizations to organize in a particular way. Those are legal questions.

Answer (score -1):

I would argue yes.

If the organisation is a person under law then its creation, existence and ultimate dissolution exist under some jurisdiction's law. You can't have a company in Australia that doesn't fall under the Corporations Act for example.

Therefore an organisation's constitution, charter, by-laws or whatever are ultimately a creature of that law and questions about "Is this constitution legal?" or even on the interpretation of the constitution notwithstanding their legality are legal questions.

However, the question you have suggested is off-topic because its a treasure hunt. If you find the rule come back and ask if its legal.